# Vivado 2016.3 unconstrained array of record with unconstrained std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx, vivado

I am experimenting to synthesise some VHDL 2008 code in Vivado 2016.3 (the same situation is in 2016.4)

The idea is to be able to have unconstrained array in record and at the same time have unconstrained array of these records.

Relevant code:

(axi_pkg.vhd)

```
-- axi_pkg.vhd
-- Author: Bruno Kremel (CERN BE-RF-FB)
-- Date: 2016-01-23
-- Description: AXI4 Package

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use work.misc_pkg.all;

package axi_pkg is
    type axis_in is record
        tdata  : std_logic_vector;
        tvalid : std_logic;
        tlast  : std_logic;
        tuser  : std_logic_vector;
    end record;

    type axis_out is record
        tready : std_logic;
    end record;

    type axis_in_vector is array (natural range <>) of axis_in;
    type axis_out_vector is array (natural range <>) of axis_out;
end package;
```

(axis_reg.vhd)

```
-- axis_reg.vhd
-- Author: Bruno Kremel (CERN BE-RF-FB)
-- Date: 2016-11-22
-- Description: AXI4 Stream register

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use work.misc_pkg.all;
use work.axi_pkg.all;

entity axis_reg is
    generic (
        DATA_TYPE : string := "signed"
        );
    port (
        aresetn : in std_logic;
        aclk    : in std_logic;

        -- Input stream
        in_axis_in  : in  axis_in;
        in_axis_out : out axis_out;

        -- Output stream
        out_axis_in  : out axis_in;
        out_axis_out : in  axis_out
        );
end entity axis_reg;

architecture basic of axis_reg is
    constant OUT_DATA_W :natural := out_axis_in.tdata'length;
    constant IN_DATA_W :natural := in_axis_in.tdata'length;
    signal in_tdata_conv : std_logic_vector(OUT_DATA_W-1 downto 0);
    signal in_tuser_conv : std_logic_vector(OUT_DATA_W/8-1 downto 0);
    signal in_tdata_shd : std_logic_vector(IN_DATA_W-1 downto 0);
    signal in_tuser_shd : std_logic_vector(IN_DATA_W/8-1 downto 0);
begin

    gen_signed: if DATA_TYPE = "signed" generate
        in_tdata_conv <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(in_tdata_shd), OUT_DATA_W));
        in_tuser_conv <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(in_tuser_shd), OUT_DATA_W/8));
    end generate;

    gen_unsigned: if DATA_TYPE = "unsigned" generate
        in_tdata_conv <= std_logic_vector(resize(unsigned(in_tdata_shd), OUT_DATA_W));
        in_tuser_conv <= std_logic_vector(resize(unsigned(in_tuser_shd), OUT_DATA_W/8));
    end generate;

    reg_ctrl_inst : entity work.axis_reg_ctrl
        port map (
            aresetn => aresetn,
            aclk    => aclk,

            next_tdata  => in_tdata_conv,
            next_tuser  => in_tuser_conv,
            next_update => open,

            in_tvalid => in_axis_in.tvalid,
            in_tready => in_axis_out.tready,
            in_tlast  => in_axis_in.tlast,

            out_tdata  => out_axis_in.tdata,
            out_tvalid => out_axis_in.tvalid,
            out_tready => out_axis_out.tready,
            out_tlast  => out_axis_in.tlast,
            out_tuser  => out_axis_in.tuser
            );
end architecture;
```

(test_entity.vhd)

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use work.axi_pkg.all;

entity test_entity is
    port (
        aresetn : std_logic;
        aclk    : std_logic;

        -- Input stream
        in_axis_in  : in  axis_in_vector;
        in_axis_out : out axis_out_vector;

        -- Output stream
        out_axis_in  : out axis_in_vector;
        out_axis_out : in  axis_out_vector
        );
end entity;

architecture test of test_entity is

begin

    gen_reg : for i in 0 to in_axis_in'length-1 generate
    begin
        reg_i : entity work.axis_reg
            generic map (
                DATA_TYPE  => "signed"
                )
            port map (aresetn      => aresetn,
                      aclk         => aclk,
                      in_axis_in   => in_axis_in(i),
                      in_axis_out  => in_axis_out(i),
                      out_axis_in  => out_axis_in(i),
                      out_axis_out => out_axis_out(i));
    end generate;

end architecture;
```

And finally test_entity_top.vhd which basically constraints the sizes for synthesis:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use work.axi_pkg.all;

entity test_entity_top is
end entity;

architecture test of test_entity_top is
    constant SIZE   : natural := 10;
    constant DATA_W : natural := 16;
    signal test_axis_in : axis_in(tdata(DATA_W-1 downto 0),
                                  tuser(DATA_W/8-1 downto 0));
    signal test_axis_out : axis_out;
    signal in_axis_in : axis_in_vector(SIZE-1 downto 0)(tdata(DATA_W-1 downto 0),
                                                        tuser(DATA_W/8-1 downto 0));
    signal in_axis_out : axis_out_vector(SIZE-1 downto 0);
    signal out_axis_in : axis_in_vector(SIZE-1 downto 0)(tdata(DATA_W-1 downto 0),
                                                         tuser(DATA_W/8-1 downto 0));
    signal out_axis_out : axis_out_vector(SIZE-1 downto 0);
    signal aresetn      : std_logic;
    signal aclk         : std_logic;
begin

    tst : entity work.test_entity
        port map (aresetn      => aresetn,
                  aclk         => aclk,
                  in_axis_in   => in_axis_in,
                  in_axis_out  => in_axis_out,
                  out_axis_in  => out_axis_in,
                  out_axis_out => out_axis_out
                  );
end architecture;
```

This all nicely compiles in ModelSim. But Vivado is reluctant to sythesise it... With this error:

```
ERROR: [Synth 8-2190] illegal syntax for subtype indication [/home/bkremel/test_vivado/test_entity_top.vhd:15]
ERROR: [Synth 8-2235] indexed name prefix type axis_in_vector expects 1 dimensions [/home/bkremel/test_vivado/test_entity_top.vhd:15]
ERROR: [Synth 8-2190] illegal syntax for subtype indication [/home/bkremel/test_vivado/test_entity_top.vhd:18]
ERROR: [Synth 8-2235] indexed name prefix type axis_in_vector expects 1 dimensions [/home/bkremel/test_vivado/test_entity_top.vhd:18]
ERROR: [Synth 8-1031] in_axis_in is not declared [/home/bkremel/test_vivado/test_entity_top.vhd:28]
ERROR: [Synth 8-1031] out_axis_in is not declared [/home/bkremel/test_vivado/test_entity_top.vhd:30]
ERROR: [Synth 8-1568] actual of formal out port out_axis_in cannot be an expression [/home/bkremel/test_vivado/test_entity_top.vhd:30]
INFO: [Synth 8-2810] unit test ignored due to previous errors [/home/bkremel/test_vivado/test_entity_top.vhd:9]
```

Which indicate it does actually accept the syntax of record constraint:

```
signal test_axis_in : axis_in(tdata(DATA_W-1 downto 0),
                              tuser(DATA_W/8-1 downto 0));
```

While it does not like:

```
signal in_axis_in : axis_in_vector(SIZE-1 downto 0)(tdata(DATA_W-1 downto 0),
                                                tuser(DATA_W/8-1 downto 0));
```

What would you suggest to use intead of unconstrained arrays and records?

The thing is that my design quite often changes the bit size of the stream.. So using generic packages would be quite inelegant (especially this register is nice example when in one file you have the bus with different sizes of data bus)

So far I have used one dimensional slv without records with manual indexing using functions/procedures, but that is quite messy to maintain...

I also add edaplayground example of relevant code https://www.edaplayground.com/x/eiC (to demonstrate that it works in simulator)...

Edit:

What is interesting is, that it actually synthesise if I do following:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use work.axi_pkg.all;

entity test_entity_top is
end entity;

architecture test of test_entity_top is
    constant SIZE   : natural := 4;
    constant DATA_W : natural := 16;
    subtype axis_in_constr is axis_in(tdata(DATA_W-1 downto 0),
                                      tuser(DATA_W/8-1 downto 0));
    subtype axis_out_constr is axis_out;

    signal ch0, ch1, ch2, ch3 : axis_in_constr;
    signal out0, out1, out2, out3 : axis_in_constr;
    signal in_axis_in : axis_in_vector := (ch0, ch1, ch2, ch3);
    signal out_axis_in : axis_in_vector := (out0, out1, out2, out3);
    signal in_axis_out : axis_out_vector(SIZE-1 downto 0);
    signal out_axis_out : axis_out_vector(SIZE-1 downto 0);
    signal aresetn      : std_logic;
    signal aclk         : std_logic;
begin

    tst : entity work.test_entity
        port map (aresetn      => aresetn,
                  aclk         => aclk,
                  in_axis_in   => in_axis_in,
                  in_axis_out  => in_axis_out,
                  out_axis_in  => out_axis_in,
                  out_axis_out => out_axis_out
                  );
end architecture;
```

So that means that the array of records with unconstrained array is actually supported, but the direct constraint syntax is not.

Any ideas how to define it less elaboratively? Although it's not big deal to define top-level like this.. Still I would not mind to avoid it, it looks a bit hacky...

Thanks
Bruno

Comment: Not sure about the crash, but it looks like your `in_axis_in` and `out_axis_in` ports should have type `axis_in_vector` not `axis_in`. Either that, or remove the range constraint on these ports.

Comment: Yes. It contains mistakes. Simulate it first and fix those. Start with the missing library/use clauses, then the missing constraints in the package. Compiling the package : ` ghdl -a axi_pkg.vhd
axi_pkg.vhd:6:9: element declaration of unconstrained array type "std_logic_vector" is not allowed` the first problem is pretty clear.

Comment: Hi Bruno, as the others say, there are errors that need fixing. I didn't like the unconstrained field in the record, but it seems that it is legal in 2008 (I've learnt something). It's a bit fiddly to use, though: [https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5Gd3](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5Gd3). The next problem is you trying to make the `tuser` field the same width. I can't think how you might do that. I wonder whether generic packages might be a better way to go, assuming you can synthesise them.

Comment: I have rectified my question with your suggestions. Now it is completely unconstrained and it is arguably quite elegant.. It works in ModelSim as stated in original question... But Vivado seems to refuse it anyway... @BrianDrummond Unconstrained arrays in records is 2008 feature... Which according to Vivado documentation should be supported...

Comment: Indeed compiling for VHDL-2008 eliminates the unconstrained vector error, my apologies.  But leaves `axi_pkg.vhd:9:41: prefix must denote an array object or type` where the prefix is `tdata`. Which IS an array, but I'm not sure it's visible before `end record`, similar usage in a port list wouldn't be. If VHDL hadn't abandoned discriminated records when it simplified from Ada, this would be trivial...

Comment: @BrianDrummond Yes. That I have fixed by making it completely unconstrained. Now I have changed the question and added link to edapleyground with working code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Xilinx SR we had come to working example of desired behaviour, so I post it here as it works in Vivado as well as ModelSim/Edaplayground.

```
-- axi_pkg.vhd
-- Author: Bruno Kremel (CERN BE-RF-FB)
-- Date: 2016-01-23
-- Description: AXI4 Package

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

package axi_pkg is
    type axis_downstream is record
        tdata  : std_logic_vector;
        tvalid : std_logic;
        tlast  : std_logic;
        tuser  : std_logic_vector;
    end record;

    type axis_upstream is record
        tready : std_logic;
    end record;

    type axis_downstream_vector is array (natural range <>) of axis_downstream;
    type axis_upstream_vector is array (natural range <>) of axis_upstream;
end package;


library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use work.axi_pkg.all;

entity test_entity_top is
end entity;

architecture test of test_entity_top is
    constant SIZE   : natural := 4;
    constant DATA_W : natural := 16;

    signal axis_downstream : axis_downstream_vector(SIZE-1 downto 0)(tdata(DATA_W-1 downto 0),
                                                                     tuser(DATA_W/8-1 downto 0));
    signal axis_upstream : axis_upstream_vector(SIZE-1 downto 0);
begin
    assert axis_downstream'length = SIZE
        report "SIZE is not correct"
    severity failure;

    assert axis_downstream(0).tdata'length = DATA_W
        report "TDATA width is not correct"
    severity failure;

    assert axis_downstream(0).tuser'length = (DATA_W/8)
        report "TUSER width is not correct"
    severity failure;

end architecture;
```

The problem is that not all files were marked as 2008 in Vivado (my fault). But I post this minimal example so that it nicely fit the question.
Also Edaplayground link: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3sKr